# How to provide port no in send email task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

Is there anyway that we can provide port no (587) instead of port 25 in ssis email send task

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/sending-mail-within-ssis-part-2-script.html) could help you.
I have had several problems with that task so I started to use the [sp sendbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql) from the database, easier to modify and to use for me.
Unfortunatelly, and by weird that it seems, there is no a natural way to do it parametricing the component.